# Change document's font using Open XML

Tags: java, fonts, ms-word, openxml, document

I'm having trouble to change fonts of a document by using Open XML. I tried to use PrependChild to apply the new font to paragraph. However, it threw the exception "Cannot insert the OpenXmlElement "newChild" because it is part of a tree.". After some research, I found out that I need to clone that element into a seperate object and make changes there, so I made this approach

```
clonedRun = (Run)runList[j].CloneNode(true);                      
clonedRun.PrependChild(runProp);
runList[j] = clonedRun;
```

but that exception message still comes out. I tried to remove that run's parent element to make it not part of a tree anymore, however, its parent is null (of course).

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (var doc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(@"mydoc.docx", true))
    {
        RunProperties runProp = new RunProperties(); // Create run properties.
        RunFonts runFont = new RunFonts();           // Create font
        runFont.Ascii = "Arial";                     // Specify font family
        FontSize size = new FontSize();
        size.Val = new StringValue("48");  // 48 half-point font size
        runProp.Append(runFont);
        runProp.Append(size);

        var clonedParagraph = new Paragraph();
        var clonedRun = new Run();

        var paragraphList = doc.MainDocumentPart.RootElement.Descendants<Paragraph>()
            .ToList<Paragraph>();
        for (int i = 0; i < paragraphList.Count; i++)
        {
            clonedParagraph = (Paragraph)paragraphList[i].CloneNode(true);
            var runList = clonedParagraph.Elements<Run>().ToList();

            for (int j = 0; j < runList.ToList().Count; j++)
            {
                clonedRun = (Run)runList[j].CloneNode(true);                      
                clonedRun.PrependChild(runProp);
                runList[j] = clonedRun;
            }
            paragraphList[i] = clonedParagraph;
        }
        doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Save();
    }
}
```

Here's the inner XML of clonedNode

```xml
<w:r w:rsidRPr="00E474DB" xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main">
    <w:rPr>
        <w:rFonts w:ascii="Calibri" w:hAnsi="Calibri" w:eastAsia="ＭＳ Ｐゴシック" w:cs="Calibri" />
        <w:sz w:val="48" />
        <w:szCs w:val="48" />
        <w:lang w:eastAsia="ja-JP" />       
    </w:rPr>
    <w:t>Curriculum Vitae</w:t>
</w:r>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue of my code. What I need to do is make changes down to the RunPropeties element, instead of Run. Below is my new working code

```
using (var doc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(@"D:\FSoft_CV - ThangPQ.docx", true))
        {               
            Body body = doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body;
            //Get all paragraphs
            var lstParagrahps = body.Descendants<Paragraph>().ToList();
            foreach (var para in lstParagrahps)
            {
                var subRuns = para.Descendants<Run>().ToList();
                foreach (var run in subRuns)
                {
                    var subRunProp = run.Descendants<RunProperties>().ToList().FirstOrDefault();

                    var newFont = new RunFonts();
                    newFont.Ascii = "Algerian";
                    newFont.EastAsia = "Algerian";

                    if (subRunProp != null)
                    {
                        var font = subRunProp.Descendants<RunFonts>().FirstOrDefault();
                        subRunProp.ReplaceChild<RunFonts>(newFont, font);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var tmpSubRunProp = new RunProperties();
                        tmpSubRunProp.AppendChild<RunFonts>(newFont);
                        run.AppendChild<RunProperties>(tmpSubRunProp);
                    }

                }        
            }
            doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Save();
            doc.Close();
        }
```